# How to make a data-(value) javascript on modal to Php value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display to a image value on modal but the image does not display on modal but it has a value, I don't know how to call it, this is my code on `href` for modal:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-img="<?php echo $row['ser_image']; ?>" image-img="<?php echo $row['ser_image']; ?>" title="View Message" class="open-image btn btn-success" href="#openimage"><i class="icon icon-eye"></i>View</a>
```

and for the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".open-image", function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

var _self = $(this);

var image = _self.data('img');
$("#img").val(image);

$(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
</script>
```

and for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="openimage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o">    </i> View Image</h4>

                </div>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <td width="50" align="center"><input src="img" id="img" >

                        <?php echo "<img  src='".urlencode(img)."' id='img'>"; ?></td> 


                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Discard</button>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: i put the image on <input> so i  am sure that it has the value, how can i make? to php value? i want to echo it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `val()` on an `<img>` tag.

`val()` is used for getting and setting `value` on form controls

---

Use `attr()` to set the `src`

```
$("#img").attr('src',image);
```

Comment: should i replace it or it is ok just to add below it?

Comment: replace it , using `val()` doesn't do anything with `<img>`

Comment: anyways it worked now,  but is it possible that i can convert it to a Php value? like <Php echo $img; ?> just like that to make it easier? i find javacript so hard for  me

Comment: not if you intend to make it dynamic based on user events

Comment: i don't understand what you are asking